# How can I rename files/change their extensions based on mimetype with a script?

Tags: command-line, files, batch, file-type

I'm hoping someone can explain to me how I can change a file type.  I recently uploaded my pictures onto my laptop and half of them are saved as a file and not an image meaning I cannot upload them onto websites for printing.

I'm looking for step by step process and also if i can do them all at the same time or have they to be done individually. I have 500+ to change.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `mimetype` utility - from `man mimetype`:

```
NAME
       mimetype - Determine file type

SYNOPSIS
       mimetype [options] [-] files

DESCRIPTION
       This script tries to determine the mime type of a file using the Shared
       MIME-info database. It is intended as a kind of file(1) work-alike, but
       uses mimetypes instead of descriptions.
```

So for example:

```
$ mimetype somefile
somefile: image/jpeg
```

However, by default, `mimetype` will "believe" the extension if present - so:

```
$ cp somefile somefile.gif
$ mimetype somefile.gif
somefile.gif: image/gif
```

You can tell it to use only the file's *magic bytes* to do the determination by adding the `-M` switch:

```
$ mimetype -M somefile.gif
somefile.gif: image/jpeg
```

and you can add `-b` to give a `brief` description:

```
$ mimetype -bM somefile.gif
image/jpeg
```

---

If you wanted to *script* the renaming, I'd suggest something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r -d '' f; do
  mt="$(mimetype -bM "$f")"
  ext="${mt##*/}"
  case "$ext" in
    jpeg|gif|png)
      echo mv -v "$f" "$f.$ext"
      ;;
    *)
    echo "skipping mimetype $mt... "
      ;;
  esac
done < <(find -type f -print0)
```

NOTES:

1. it doesn't actually rename anything as written: the `echo mv` just outputs what it *would* do - please check and double check that it is behaving as expected on **your** files before removing the `echo`
2. it only operates on `jpeg`,`gif`, and `png` files: if there are other image types, you will need to add those explicitly
3. it will rename (add an additional extension to) any files it considers to have the *wrong* extension, based on magic bytes

**There may be other - easier - options using tools like `exiftool`**